How to accumulate shift duration with day setting
I have a shift class, that returns the information for the shift.
public class Shift {
    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;
    public Long getShiftDuration() {
        long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end);
        
        return minutes;
    }
    
    public String getBusinessDate() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateStr = getStart().toLocalDate().format(formatter);
        return dateStr;
    }
}

Then I have a class DaySettingFlat, that contains the list of dates that we need to calculate sum of shift durations. The date mentioned in DaySettingFlat contains a variable businessDate which will contain a date. With this date value we have to sum the durations of the Shift collection that matched with the businessDate.
public class DaySettingFlat {
    String businessDate;
    Integer sumOfShiftDuration;
}

The both class is registered as @ProblemFactCollectionProperty. Now for each DaySettingFlat entry, we have to sum the duration of the shifts for a date stored in businessDate. Both the Shift and DaySettingFlat are used as a collection.
I tried like follows but it's not working, it's giving compilation error:
    Constraint daySettingStandardNumberOfHours(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(DaySettingFlat.class)
                .join(Shift.class, equal(DaySettingFlat::getBusinessDate, Shift::getStartDate))
//Getting error on group by 
                .groupBy(Shift::getStartDate,
                         ConstraintCollectors.toList(),
                         ConstraintCollectors.sumLong(Shift::getShiftDuration))
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (date, list, totalDuration)->{
                    return totalDuration;
                }).asConstraint("daySettingStandardNumberOfHours");
    }


With your reputation and thus experience on SO you should know that "it's not working" doesn't really help. Can you elaborate on in what way it isn't working?

As an aside I would use Duration for a shift duration and for the sum of same, for clearer code than you get with int (and Integer, don’t know why you introduced an object there).

The reason it is not working is because you have a BiConstraintStream, so you need to provide a function that takes both DaySettingFlat and Shift:
    Constraint daySettingStandardNumberOfHours(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(DaySettingFlat.class)
                .join(Shift.class, equal(DaySettingFlat::getBusinessDate, Shift::getStartDate))
                .groupBy((day, shift) -> shift.getStartDate(),
                         ConstraintCollectors.toList((day, shift) -> day),
                         ConstraintCollectors.sumLong((day, shift) -> shift.getShiftDuration()))
                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (date, list, totalDuration)->{
                    return totalDuration;
                }).asConstraint("daySettingStandardNumberOfHours");
    }

Is the list doing anything? It is unused in the Constraint you provided. If not, I recommend removing it.

And a note: you can use sumDuration https://javadoc.io/static/ai.timefold.solver/timefold-solver-core/1.11.0/ai/timefold/solver/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintCollectors.html#sumDuration(java.util.function.BiFunction) if you modified getShiftDuration to return Duration.
